# Laravel storage folder images are not accessible on live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I was try to show images in my application. Images are store inside storage folder.

I have tried php artisan storage:link command for creating storage link. Even after creating symbolic link it did not worked. I also tried to create symbolic link with routes but nothing works for me . On local server the images are working fine but getting issue on server,  I am using laravel 8 version .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely to be permission issue. Try to adjust your live storage folder’s permission. If you’re using linux, you can use chmod.

Comment: the storage folder has 775 permission , Is it ok?